# Why string theory action needs to be manifestly diffeomorphism invariant?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, string-theory, gauge-theory, diffeomorphism-invariance

A typical  QFT action is obviously not diff invariant, in other words, the integration parameters have physical significance as time and position. For example action for  massless free scalar field on flat space time is obviously not diff invariant.

However, we need string theory action to be diff invariant. I believe it is because of the Polyakov path integral formalism. In Polyakov path integral we sum over all possible geometries and topologies of world sheet manifold. However, if action is not diff in variant, it means that we have a fixed parametrization of a world sheet, and I think one can not parametrize all possible world sheet manifold with one specific parametrization. Is that correct?

In other words I need a geometrical explanation, on why this invariance should be **manifest**.

Comment: Think of a particle's worldline. The parameter we choose to label its points is arbitrary. The physical object is the geometrical curve in spacetime. That's why reparameterization invariance matters. The same holds for the string and its worldsheet.

Comment: @gold I can formulate particle in a  parametrization fixed form in that case it would not be diff invariant.  but it would still describe a correct physics. so that invariance should be **manifest**. e.g. $\int dt \sqrt{1-\dot{x}^2}$ this is not parametrization invariant, but it is definetely physically correct system.

Comment: I think it would be difficult to use the same parameterization for two manifolds that had different topologies! What would it mean to give a circle and the real line the same parameterization? Or a circle and a finite line segment?

Comment: @andrew yes i agree thats the main problem in my opinion. you cant add interactions in path integral formalism if we fix parametrization.

Comment: @physshyp I agree, since the worldsheet is a dynamical object, you can't really say in advance of solving a dynamical equation how to parameterize it.

Comment: @andrew in canonical quantization of string theory they usually work with non manifestly  diff invariant theory. i.e. phase space action of string theory, which is not manifestly diff invariant.